# Allow Admob to Display Video ads

Tags: android, admob

I have an application displaying interstitial ads perfectly, but they are just images, and as a generation living on videos, I think it would be beneficial to allow Admob to display Video ads as well.

Do I have to add extra permissions for that? Or what I should do differently?

Here is how I display ads;

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(Main.this);
// Insert the Ad Unit ID
interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-...442");

//Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml

// Request for Ads
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

// Add a test device to show Test Ads
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("")
      .build();

// Load ads into Banner Ads
//adView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Load ads into Interstitial Ads
Runnable r = new Runnable () {

    @Override
    public void run() {
          interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
};

runOnUiThread(r);
// Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  public void onAdLoaded() {
      // Call displayInterstitial() function
     displayInterstitial();
  }
 });
```

And just these two permissions;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The ads are displayed fine but they are only Image ads, I want VIDEOS!!

Answer (score 17):

There's no way to display video ads programmatically in your project/app. However, in the admob console, you can specify the kind of interstitial ad types( `Text, Image, Video`) that should be served within your app.

By default `Text, Image, Video` ad types should be enabled for interstitials. You can disable the Text and Image ad types if you want to restrict to only video ads, however note this will lead to a lower fill rate resulting in a decrease in revenue. Also note that video ads will fail to load when users have a poor/slow internet connection while using your ap.

Just go to Monetize -> Select your app -> Click the interstitial ad unit -> Enable/Disable ad types

[image]

Comment: Have you tried only image or video ads? Did this increase your revenue?

Comment: I tried. It increases revenue only is US. For other countries, video ads rarely get served leading to a low revenue

Comment: Thank you. I am debating about removing the txt ads. I figure users do not like those? Do you remove them as well and just show image or video ads?

Comment: Only for games. For apps I use all ad types. You can try using only image /video ads. After some time if it doesn't affect your revenue, you can revert to showing all ad types ..IMO

Comment: Hi guys, let me ask a question to you. Does google pay for watched video ads ? I mean ads that we force user to watch for at least 5 secs.Thanks

Comment: What is the advantage of Video ad? In my app so many video ads are played, but not clicked. That time I didn't get any revenuer to let the video played. So i think it's just wastage of mobile data. I am feeling it like a full screen ad if excluded mobile data lose.

Comment: could you give me more information about only video ads revenue please

Comment: Where can I find how much each type gives you? Also, is there a way to set how long the video ads will be?