# Android - adding video advertisement to the app

Tags: java, android, video, ads

Could anybody give me some directions on how to add a video ad. to my android app, I couldn't find anything on Google. Can someone explain it to me step by step?

Comment: do you want to play the ad from the internet? or store it locally and play it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594497/allow-admob-to-display-video-ads

Comment: http://vungle.com/blog/2015/07/31/how-to-monetize-your-android-app-with-mobile-video-ads-in-10-minutes/

Comment: I want to show it from internet

Comment: You can use AdColony, I work with it and its great! The implementation is very easy and they provide with example apps. check the link: http://www.adcolony.com/

Comment: Google is very strict with advertisement and monetizing, they will say nothing about adColony?

Comment: Do I need a merchant google account for this?

Comment: AdColony have nothing to do with Google! Is other ads enterprise that provide video ads too. You have to create an account and configure the app in adcolony. You have a lot more ads enterprise like Tapjoy, AppLovin, ChartBoost, Mopub, etc...

Comment: Ok thanks! Google has banned my app but I will try this. Write an answer and I'll set it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of Ads providers out there, few examples: Tapjoy, AppLovin, ChartBoost, MoPub...
For Video Ads, AdColony is a great provider, and is very easy to setup and code. Also they gives a few project with differents alternatives to implement. 
Test it: adcolony.com