# Admob video Interstitial test/dummy id

Tags: android, admob

Is there a test id for admob interstitial video ad ?

i know dummy test id for banner and image interstitial

> Banner : ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
>
> Interstitial:ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

i need dummy test id for video interstitial

i already know how to add test device id

```
 AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
    .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

but i want to give demo to some other guy whose device id is unknown

so can some one give me the

### Test id for video interstetial

thanks in advance

Comment: By "video interstitial", do you mean "Rewarded Ads"? https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video

Comment: i ment something like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594497/allow-admob-to-display-video-ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered here : [How can I get device ID for Admob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524752/how-can-i-get-device-id-for-admob)

you can make the current running device into an adview test device programmatically

```
if(YourApplication.debugEnabled(this)) //debug flag from somewhere that you set
    {

        String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String deviceId = md5(android_id).toUpperCase();
        mAdRequest.addTestDevice(deviceId);
        boolean isTestDevice = mAdRequest.isTestDevice(this);

        Log.v(TAG, "is Admob Test Device ? "+deviceId+" "+isTestDevice); //to confirm it worked
    }
```

You need to use the md5 of the Android ID, and it needs to be upper case. Here is the md5 code I used

```
public static final String md5(final String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Logger.logStackTrace(TAG,e);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: i know that ,  i don't know what device the client will be using when he tests my app

Comment: this code will help you to get the device id from the clients device, and then sends request to get the ad.

Comment: /* String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String deviceId = md5(android_id).toUpperCase(); */ [FOR GETTING Device ID]

        /*mAdRequest.addTestDevice(deviceId); */ [REQUESTING TO ADD TEST DEVICE]

Comment: this works but it still displays image interstetial but not, video interstetial