# How to get a Test ad unit ID for rewarded video ads for Android?

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to test a rewarded video in my Android app but I don't want to use my real id since they can close my account. Where can I get a test unit ID for this?

Edit: using admob

```
 private void loadAd(){

if(!mAd.isLoaded()){
  mAd.loadAd("TEST_ID",
      new AdRequest.Builder()
          .build());
}


  }
```

Comment: What network are you using?

Comment: @TincoDeSimone admob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Admob video Interstitial test/dummy id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542999/admob-video-interstitial-test-dummy-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to your mediation network panel and enable test ads, is not through code when you have mediation

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, Admob introduced their own rewarded video in early March 2017 and since this time its been enabled by default for rewarded ad units. This means that if you've set up an Admob unit to point to mediated providers using suitable test settings at the providers end it will serve live Admob rewarded videos (and revenue) depending on the mediation settings see this:
[admob sdk forum that provided a dummy rewarded unit ID](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/k-kVwVu2XBc)